# How to pass data to a react modal?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal, react-modal

I am trying to perform the following

- Call a modal on a button click from say `page 1`.
- Show the data passed from `page 1` as content in the modal.
- Come back to the `page 1` on clicking the close button on the modal.

I wish to use a react modal to serve this purpose.

Comment: Talk some code please!

Answer (score 0):

You can look any react model library

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal
```

it has the example also, please check it